# content of html not send using sendgrid in php

Tags: php, sendgrid

i  am trying to send message via send grid bt when i will add html enter code here tag in message mmessage doesn't sent.....

```
$subject = 'Confirmation';
$to =  $email;
$from = "no-reply@xxxx.com";
$message .= '&nbsp;'; 
// Compose a simple HTML email message
$message= '<div style="width:70%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">dcdde</div>';
sendemail($from,$subject,$to,$message);

function sendemail($f,$s,$t,$m){ 
    $from = new SendGrid\Email(null, $f);
    $subject = $s;
    $to = new SendGrid\Email(null, $t);   
   $content = new SendGrid\Content("text/plain", $m);
    $mail = new SendGrid\Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content);
    $apiKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);
    $response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);
     $response->statusCode();
     $res= $response->headers();
     $response->body();
}
```

Comment: did u set your headers to use html/text ?

Comment: yeah i did.. bt still doen't work